# Does flash/flex have `matrix` for image scaling as Android?

Tags: android, flash, apache-flex, matrix

I wrote an Android application, which I used `android.graphics.Matrix` to zoom/rotate/move images. The most important thing is the 9 values in the `matrix`:

> MSCALE_X, MSKEW_X, MTRANS_X, MSKEW_Y, MSCALE_Y, MTRANS_Y, MPERSP_0, MPERSP_1, MPERSP_2

And now I want to development a same application in flash/flex. I wonder if flash/flex has the same `matrix` as Android? If I get the 9 values from Android's matrix, can I use it direct in flash/flex?

Comment: @wvxvw Would Matrix3D be used to skew items?

Comment: Fortunately, I don't need skew in my application :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does have a Matrix Class.

ASDocs for [Matrix](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html) Class.

There is also a [Matrix3D class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix3D.html)

I have no idea how this relates to the Android classes in terms of functionality.